# How to make bold a part of NSMutableString?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have this code in my hands:

```
if let text = trimText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableString {
    text.insertString("\(prefix) ", atIndex: 0)
    textStorage.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: text as String)
}
```

When I try to change my `text` as:

```
text = attributedTextFunc(text)
```

where

```
func attributedTextFunc(str: NSString) -> NSAttributedString {

    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)])

    let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15.0)]

    attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: str.rangeOfString("More"))

    return attributedString
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'NSAttributedString' to type 'NSMutableString'
```

How can I make it bold?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assing NSAttributedString to text. It's two different types.

String is not subclassed from NSAttributedString.

You should set:

```
attributedText = attributedTextFunc(text)
```

Then if you want to present it on UILabel

```
label.attributedText = attributedText
```

**UPDATE**

Struct String doesn't know anything about UIKit and Bold styles.

NSAttributedString knows about UIKit and contains any text styles you want

**UPDATE 2**

In your case

```
ReadMoreTextView.attributedTrimText = attributedText
```

Comment: I'm using this library https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView, and I want to change the trimmed text color and make it bold. But I cannot =/

Comment: Yes, you should do it inside this library.

Comment: @Doe You want to make bold `Read More` text?

Comment: Try to use this initializer convenience init(maximumNumberOfLines: Int, attributedTrimText: NSAttributedString?, shouldTrim: Bool) also use that attributedTrimText property instead text

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reassign `text` because:

- `text` is constant (`let`)
- `text` is `NSMutableString`, but `attributedTextFunc` return `NSAttributedString`

You have to store result of `attributedTextFunc` in variable as a `NSAttributeString` and set `attributeText` of `UILabel` instead of `text`

```
if let text = trimText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableString {
    // ...
    let attributeText = attributedTextFunc(text)
    someLabel.attributeText = attributeText
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code and pass your normal String and Bold String (which is needed to be bold).

```
func attributeStrings(first: String, second : String) -> NSMutableAttributedString{
        let myNormalAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: first,
                                                         attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)])
        let myAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: second,
                                                   attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()])
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        result.appendAttributedString(myNormalAttributedTitle)
        result.appendAttributedString(myAttributedTitle)
        return result
    }
```

and assign the return value of this function to

```
someLabel.attributeText = attributeStrings("My Name is", second : "Himanshu")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, your `text` is type of NSMutableString and your function `attributedTextFunc` is type of NSString.

That is the problem so just change it from NSString to NSMutableString.

Comment: NSMutableString is sublass from NSString, problem is in NSAttributedString. NSAttributedString is not subclass from NSString